# Why are there no tips when allocating an object in xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode5

For example:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] init];
```

When I write `UITapGestureRecognizer alloc`, there are no tips, so I have to write `UITapGestureRecognizer` by myself, but it's a little long and time-consuming. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: You can write your own Xcode plugin to fix it. Other than that, [file a bug report](http://bugreport.apple.com/) is all you can do.

Comment: Maybe your formatting's off somewhere in your code... For example, perhaps you're missing a bracket somewhere so Xcode won't help autocomplete your statements. What happens when you try to run the app?

Comment: Try cleaning the project. That sometimes fixes strange xcode bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should auto complete by default? When you type `=` always type in `[];` first, then go back to type `UITapGestureRecognizer alloc`.

Make sure your code completion is enabled by doing the following:

- Go to XCode Preferences
- Text Editing
- Tick "Suggest completions while typing"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Type the opening bracket `[` first before you type the class name. That way XCode knows you are expecting a class.